# what is following design technically called? How it can be implemented in code?

Tags: html, css, user-interface, frontend, web-frontend

[you will see this thing generally when you visit a website or an app for first time, It is also used to describe new features on websites to users.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qGYYX.png)

Answer (score 0):

Go on the site where you saw it, right click on it, select inspect element, that will give you an idea of the code used. This kind of thing can be achieved by means of a modal window, popup ,layover etc.